# Blazor OnAfterRender is not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I am trying to scroll to the bottom of a scroll-able tbody after dynamically adding <tr> s using data from an API. And I am calling a method in js interop to do that. But when i try to access the tbody it shows that tbody is null. Why the tbody is null if rendering is completed?

```
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender || isScrollToBottomEvent ) goToBottom();
    }


    private async void goToBottom()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToBottom");
        if (Postman.AddedNewRecord)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showLastRecord");
            Postman.NotifyNewRecordState(false);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("printing from the goToBottom. Invoking the ShowLastRecord in JSInterop");
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("setting isScrollToBottomEvent to false");
        isScrollToBottomEvent = false;
    }
```

I am calling the goToBottom() method in from OnAfterRender. And the first line in the goToBottom() method invokes in this case.

```
function scrollToBottom()
{
    console.log("scrollToBottom() : interop");
    const tbodyData = document.getElementById('tbody-data');

    const scrollHeight = tbodyData.scrollHeight;
    tbodyData.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
}
```

This is the JS method.
Code works okay but the console shows a warning about null scroll height.

When I try to add null checking to the scrollToBottom() befor setting scrollTop , the conditional for null invokes.

```
function scrollToBottom()
{
    console.log("scrollToBottom() : interop");
    const tbodyData = document.getElementById('tbody-data');

     if(tbodyData){
        const scrollHeight = tbodyData.scrollHeight;
         tbodyData.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
     }else{
         console.warn("tbody is not loaded yet scrollToBottom aborted : interop");
    }

}
```

After modifying the js method the console warn line prints in the console and scrolling does not happen.

Comment: My guess is you are getting data asynchronously and the await is yielding control to the component.  It does a first render and the `OnAfterRenderAsync`  event gets called before there's any data in the form.  You almost certainly need to do the call in a subsequent  `OnAfterRenderAsync` event that gets raised when the initial component lifecycle completes [and your dataset exists].  Don't use `firstRender`, add a `_dataLoaded` bool or check if the dataset is empty.  Know https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0 inside out.